# Terraform aws-lb-target-group problems

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-elb

My situation is as follows:
I’m creating a AWS ECS (NGINX container for SFTP traffic) FARGATE setup with Terraform with a network load balancer infront of it. I’ve got most parts set-up just fine and the current setup works. But now i want to add more target groups to the setup so i can allow more different ports to the container. My variable part is as follows:

```
variable "sftp_ports" {
  type = map
  default = {
    test1 = {
      port = 50003
    }
    test2 = {
      port = 50004
    }
  }
}
```

and the actual deployment is as follows:

```
resource "aws_alb_target_group" "default-target-group" {

  name        = local.name
  port        = var.sftp_test_port
  protocol    = "TCP"
  target_type = "ip"
  vpc_id      = data.aws_vpc.default.id
  depends_on = [
    aws_lb.proxypoc
  ]
}

resource "aws_alb_target_group" "test" {
  for_each = var.sftp_ports

  name        = "sftp-target-group-${each.key}"
  port        = each.value.port
  protocol    = "TCP"
  target_type = "ip"
  vpc_id      = data.aws_vpc.default.id

  depends_on = [
    aws_lb.proxypoc
  ]
}

resource "aws_alb_listener" "ecs-alb-https-listenertest" {
  for_each = var.sftp_ports
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.proxypoc.id
  port              = each.value.port
  protocol          = "TCP"

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.default-target-group.arn
  }
}
```

This deploys the needed listeners and the target groups just fine but the only problem i have is on how i can configure the registered target part. The aws ecs service resource only allows one target group arn so i have no clue on how i can add the additional target groups in order to reach my goal. I've been wrapping my head around this problem and scoured the internet but so far .. nothing. So is it possible to configure the ecs service to contain more target groups arns or am i supposed to configure only single target group with multiple ports (as far as i know, this is not supported out of the box, checked the docs as well. But it is possible to add multiple registered targets in the GUI so i guess it is a possibility)?

I’d like to hear from you guys,
Thanks!

Comment: Well, you have two TGs, which means you would have to use two listeners, but in the code you pasted you are referencing a TG not present in your code.

Comment: Yea, that's correct. That was more of a test i tried, seeing as i have no clue on how to solve this problem. I was hoping by pointing the listener to the existing (it was a test target group which worked but it was a hard-coded single port instead of the above code and is currently connected to the ECS cluster) one that i could proceed but this was not the case. 

I have created new target groups as you can see but those are not connected to the ECS cluster. So that's the confusion. But is it a possibility to use the existing one and register more targets?

I'll add the other TG to the pos

Comment: If you are using Fargate, try switching the `target_type` to `instance`.

Comment: It's not compatible with the AWSVPC network mode.

Comment: I got it working via a different route. I created a NLB with the same configuration and this worked so i skipped the ECS part completely and just redirected the traffic from the NLB to the backend server. And to be honest, it cleaned up the code a lot and works just as well! Thanks for the help anyway!